# Are broadcast receivers guaranteed to receive every broadcast announcement intended for them?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

A fellow developer and I have started to question whether a broadcast announcement is guaranteed to be received by the appropriate broadcast receiver.

We have a broadcast receiver which receives messages that should be put on to the screen. Occasionally we notice that some messages never make it to the screen.

Even with the debugger, it has been hard to tell for certain if the receiver is not getting the broadcast or if it due to our own bugs that the broadcast is never sent.

So I wanted to ask generally if there are any known reasons why the broadcast receiver would not receive an announcement?

Answer (score 1):

There are ordered broadcasts in Android. They are sent to receivers according to the receivers priority. And receiver with a higher priority can abort the broadcast spreading.
See this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) for details.